# Group by date in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my appointment collection

```
{ _id: ObjectId("518ee0bc9be1909012000002"), date: ISODate("2013-05-13T22:00:00Z"), patient:"John" }

{ _id: ObjectId("518ee0bc9be1909012000002"), date: ISODate("2013-05-13T22:00:00Z"), patient:"alex" }

{ _id: ObjectId("518ee0bc9be1909012000002"), date: ISODate("2013-05-13T22:00:00Z"), patient:"sara" }
```

how can i get my resualt like this

```
{date: ISODate("2013-05-13T22:00:00Z"),
patients:["John","alex","sara"] }
```

i try this

```
Appointments.aggregate([
{
$group: {
_id: '$date'
}
}
], function(err, doc) {
return console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

any help please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `$push` aggregation operator to assemble the `patients` array in the `$group`:

```
Appointments.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$date', patients: {$push: '$patient'}}},
    {$project: {date: '$_id', patients: 1, _id: 0}}
], ...)
```

To include the patient ids as in your follow-up question:

```
Appointments.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$date', patients: {$push: {
        patient: '$patient'
        _id: '$_id'
    }}}},
    {$project: {date: '$_id', patients: 1, _id: 0}}
], ...)
```

Comment: thanks....
how can push _id with patient ???
{date: ISODate("2013-05-13T22:00:00Z"),
patients:
[{_id :518ee0bc9be1909012000002,patient:"John"},
{_id :518ee0bc9be1909012000002,patient:"alex"},
{_id :518ee0bc9be1909012000002,patient:"sara"}]
}

Comment: Is this done in the schema or the routes where we di the .find()

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getAllBokFilterByDate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await Book.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:"$date"}},
          count: { $sum: 1 } 
        }
      }
    ]);

    res.status(200).json({
      data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'failed',
      error
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.